# SQL Select with multiple parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to create a search page that would use multiple textboxes to build a query and output the results to the gridview but if the user only selects to complete some of the textboxes the select statement breaks and does not return results to the gridview. How do I cater for this? I tried only one variable but get a "Must declare the scalar variable " error.

ASP Code:

```
         <h2>
    Find Client</h2>

<div>
    <fieldset class="login">
        <legend>Client Detail</legend>

        <div class="columns">
            <div class="label">
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeNumber" CssClass="Smart-css_Label" runat="server">Client Number:</asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">

                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientNumber" placeholder="Client Number" runat="server" CssClass="Smart-css_Text"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="label">
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
            </div>
            <div class="label">
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" CssClass="Smart-css_Label" runat="server">Name:</asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" placeholder="Name" runat="server" CssClass="Smart-css_Text"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="label">
                <asp:Label ID="lblSurname" CssClass="Smart-css_Label" runat="server">Surname:</asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" placeholder="Surname" runat="server" CssClass="Smart-css_Text"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="label">
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
            </div>
            <div class="label">
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
            </div>
            <div class="label">
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmployer" CssClass="Smart-css_Label" runat="server">Client Type:</asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboClientType" placeholder="Client Type" CssClass="Smart-css_Combo" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div class="label">
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" CssClass="Smart-css_Label" runat="server">Client Status:</asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboClientStatus" CssClass="Smart-css_Combo" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>


            <div class="label">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" CssClass="Smart-css_Label" runat="server">Company Name:</asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" CssClass="Smart-css_Text"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="label">
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
            </div>
            <div class="label">
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
            </div>
            <div class="label">
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
            </div>
            <div class="label">
                <asp:Label ID="Label13" CssClass="Smart-css_Label" runat="server">Postal Code:</asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPostcode" runat="server" CssClass="Smart-css_Text"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="label">
                <asp:Label ID="lblMobileNo" CssClass="Smart-css_Label" runat="server">Mobile Number:</asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobileNo" runat="server" CssClass="Smart-css_Text"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
                            <div class="label">
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
            </div>


            <div class="label">
            </div>
                            <div class="textbox">
            </div>
            <div class="label">
            </div>
                            <div class="textbox">
            </div>
            <div class="label">

                <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" CssClass="Smart-css_Button" runat="server" Text="Find Client"/>
            </div>
                                            <div class="textbox">

                <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" CssClass="Smart-css_Button" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

 <div class= "widecolumns">
         <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Message" Visible="False" 
        Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
 </div>

<div class= "widecolumns">

    <asp:GridView ID="grdclientslist" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CssClass="mGrid" PageSize="5">
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
```

VB Code

```
Protected Sub cmdSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click

    Dim clientNumber As String = txtClientNumber.Text
    Dim name As String = txtName.Text
    Dim surname As String = txtSurname.Text
    Dim clientType As String = cboClientType.Text
    Dim clientStatus As String = cboClientStatus.Text
    Dim companyName As String = txtCompanyName.Text
    Dim postCode As String = txtPostcode.Text
    Dim mobileNumber As String = txtMobileNo.Text

    sqlconn.SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientNumber", clientNumber)
    sqlconn.SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name)
    sqlconn.SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surname)
    sqlconn.SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientType", clientType)
    sqlconn.SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientStatus", clientStatus)
    sqlconn.SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", companyName)
    sqlconn.SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postCode", postCode)
    sqlconn.SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobileNumber", mobileNumber)



    sqlconn.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM epm_ClientDetail WHERE (client_ID LIKE '%' + @clientNumber + '%') OR (client_Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%') OR (client_Surname LIKE '%' + @surname + '%') OR (client_Type LIKE '%' + @clientType + '%') OR (client_Status LIKE '%' + @clientStatus + '%') OR (client_CompanyName LIKE '%' + @companyName + '%') OR (client_StreetPostCode LIKE '%' + @postCode + '%') OR (client_MobileNo LIKE '%' + @mobileNumber + '%')")

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlconn.Exception) Then

        grdclientslist.DataSource = sqlconn.SQLDS.Tables(0)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you check if your textbox is empty?

Comment: First of all this query will be ultra slow. 2 - it doesn't work as all provided parameters must have value it can't be null

Comment: It's not going to solve the slowness issue, but can you just use the null-coalescing operator?  Example: `Dim clientNumber As String = If(txtClientNumber.Text, "")`

Comment: You have no chance of improving the performance of this when you use leading wildcards on every column. It will be a scan no matter what you do. Also you should limit the columns being returned to only those needed. Do NOT use select *.

Comment: You might want to consider rethinking this as it is a search type of query. Take a look at this article for some ideas on this type of thing. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: What is `epm_ClientDetail`?

Comment: epm_ClientDetail is the Tables Name

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies, would it make more sense to have a combo box to select the field I want to search against then do the select based on that. Would it help with speeding up the query?

Comment: Yes it would help because then your query doesn't have to look in all those columns. Look at doing that AND the suggestions from the article I linked previously and it will considerably help performance.

Comment: Thanks Sean, The article is a very interesting read.